# Why volume host folder is empty for docker

Tags: docker

I am using docker for windows on Win 10 Pro.

When I run a docker with volume on host, it works fine however I am unable to see any files in d:\nopdata

```
docker run -v D:\nopdata:/src/Presentation/Nop.Web -p 8181:80 nopaccelerate/nopcommerce:release-4.20
```

I am new to docker and would like to understand what is expected here? The folder i am mounting from host, i.e. d:\nopdata is empty while there should be files.

Comment: Docker mounts from host to container. So if the directory is empty, it will stay empty, until the container copy something into it.

Comment: Ok, there should be files from container, that's what I'm expecting

Comment: have you shared `D:` drive in docker settings?

Comment: Yes, I have already shared that. And I am using hosting Jenkins on docker using host volume bind, which works well and I can access files in volume from windows. So it should work with this as well. But it doesn't!

Comment: Is there a way to find out exact path in use by docker container? For example, D:\nopdata:/src/Presentation/Nop.Web here /src/Presentation/Nop.Web is correct or not that I want to ensure.